# Resizing window causes next div to show in responsive horizontal scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, responsive-design

The website displays fine on all resolutions, the problem arises when the window is resized.

So what I have done is create 5 div containers and given each container 20% width within a body of 500% width. Below is one of them

```
 <div id="workslide" class="container"> 
 //some a tags goes here
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
     bottom: 0;
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
     width: 20%;
}
```

Within each container is an img slide which is set in css `background-size: contain;` which scales correctly for all resolutions. When the window is resized from the left, for example, this happens. The previous div bleeds in :
[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated !

Comment: I noticed a similar question just a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403507/proper-window-resizing-of-full-width-ul-and-li-for-responsive-website

Comment: Responsive sliders that function via percent widths are very buggy.  It is much more reliable to use jquery to slide to the appropriate slide with `left` px values.

Comment: Really? It probably looks worse if its not responsive, so would rather work on the problem. Scrolling the body with jQuery.animate(); works fine. In the above example the next div will align and scale properly.

Comment: After the browser is resized, are you updating the scroll position of the slider? If not, see the following answer at the question @isherwood referred to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16406142/1306809

Comment: i see, i'll try something like `$(this).scrollLeft(offset().left);` right after document ready

Comment: You could consider using twitter bootstrap's carousel which is a free responsive slider that works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a fix for the problem after the pointer from Matt. Works perfect now:

```
//added following lines of code within document ready:
$(window).resize(function() {
$(window).scrollLeft($(/*element you have scrolled to*/).offset().left);
});
```